# EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider not in providers when running tests

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, spring-integration-aws

I have spring boot application which utilizes AWS Kinesis and DynamoDB.
When I run the application I can see that AWSCredentialsProviderChain is provided with EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider to read ***AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID*** and ***AWS_ACCESS_KEY*** from environment variables.

But when I run my integration test, ***EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider*** is not among AWSCredentialsProvider(s). Here is my base test class configuration:

```
@ActiveProfiles("integration")
@SpringBootTest
class BaseTest {

}
```

@SpringBootTest will take @SpringBootApplication as main configuration class and I assume both should have the same configuration context.

I appreciate your help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, in my tests I am using spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis to produce events.
when I removed it and replaced it with spring integration producer problem solved.

Combining spring cloud binder for kinesis and spring integration together is very tricky and made few issues for me. Be careful when using both in your application.